# When using Mail with Gmail IMAP, how to move emails to different folders and not label them?

Tags: mail.app, email, gmail, folders, imap

I'm using Mac Lion Mail app with Gmail IMAP and when I drag and drop or command-click to move messages from my Inbox to a folder called Personal, it appears to work in Mail.  But when I look at Gmail, the message remains in Inbox.  Instead of actually moving the message, it simply gives it the label, Personal.

In Gmail, I never label anything, I always move messages to various folders and I want to mimic this behaviour in Mail app.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 4):

Gmail has a [guide](http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=77657&topic=1668961&ctx=topic) on how actions on IMAP clients correspond to Gmail actions. In order to remove items from your inbox in Gmail, you will need to delete them from your inbox in Mail.app -- this will "archive" the message in Gmail rather than moving it to the trash. The trouble with this is that emails that you move to a folder in Mail.app probably won't show up in your Mail.app inbox until you refresh it, so it may take a few steps to move and archive a message. Unfortunately, Gmail behaves so differently from normal mail services that using it with a standard IMAP client tends to be a pain. However, the reference in the link above should help you figure out which actions in Mail.app correspond to various Gmail actions.

Comment: Thanks for the link and explaining it in depth. I just tried what you said, re-synced several times, but the message doesn't re-appear in inbox.

Answer (score 2):

I find that clicking on the folder you just moved messages to in Mail will then remove them from the Inbox. Its weird, its as if the re-downloading of the message in the folder you moved them to, kicks off the actual move in Gmail.